# Observable as a function - Observer Design Pattern java

Tags: java, function, observable

I was asked to implement events as functions but using observer interface, this doesn't make sense to me.

"Add the following events to FileEncryptor (choose correct parameter types of each event):

```
[encryptionStarted
 encryptionEnded
 decryptionEnded
 decryptionStarted]
```

Activate them in the appropriate places (the events are supposed to be expressed as methods in the interface, as you read in the Observer Design Pattern – which is the Observer and which is the Subject).

How would you know what is the time? (System class).

In the **Observer Pattern** do you have any example where each event is a function?

Comment: I don't really get your point. Anyhow, this [link](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) may help you.

Comment: i have a class named file encryptor the encrypts or decrypts files by certain key.  I was asked to add events to the class when encryption starts and ends , using observer pattern. when reading about this pattern i saw that each event should be a class. but the mission requires to make it as methods

Answer (score 1):

I will try to explain a little your case comparing the example in [here](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) with your specific case.

- `FileEncriptor`is the `ConcreteObservable`
- `encryptionStarted`, `encryptionEnded`, `decryptionEnded` and `decryptionStarted` are the `updateState`.

What those methods have to do is to call every concrete observers (implementations of an interface) so that they do their actions according to the event that is occurring at that moment.

There are thousands of examples (like [this one](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/observer_pattern.htm)) which you can use as a starting point.